# Division with decimals

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, type-conversion

I'm running the following code:

```
float fSpeed = 1 + (uRate / 10);
```

uRate is -5.

I was hoping to get the result 0.5 because (uRate / 10) should be -0.5

However, fSpeed is 0.
Does anybody see my mistake?

Thank you.

Comment: The first mistake is not providing a [mcve]

Comment: Probably integer division getting truncated. 1/2 = 0

Comment: Assuming uRate is an int and is equal to `-5`, `(uRate / 10)` produces `-1`.

Comment: Also keep in mind, that 0.5 is one of those rare cases, a floating point value can represent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write

```
float fSpeed = 1 + (uRate / 10.0f);
```

In this case the expression `(uRate / 10.0f)` will have a floating value due to the ***usual arithmetic conversions***.